# Show/hide elements with ajax

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using AJAX to load a list of comic chapters on click. It works fine. I would like to modify the script to hide the chapters when I click again on the same book. Hopefully the below pictures will make it clear.

[image: How it works:]

---

[image: How I want it:]

The code to load the chapters is as follows:

```
function aload(element) {
    var url = element.getAttribute('data-ajax-url');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4){
            document.getElementById("chapter-container").innerHTML = this.response;
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Thank you for all your suggestions.

Comment: This isn't related to AJAX. Just add a click event listener to the element that does what you want.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your feedback, I have removed AJAX from the tags.  I will try to implement your suggestion myself and will post an update.

Comment: Since you have multiple books, you could use a global variable to indicate which book you last opened. Then when you click on a book, check whether the current book is the same as the one they clicked on. If it is, hide the output container, otherwise call `aload()`.

Comment: @Barmar If you find some spare time, I would appreciate your feedback on my update.

Comment: What's the point of the `for` loop? It iterates exactly once, so it's just like doing the assignment normally.

Comment: You shouldn't make up your own attributes. If you want application-specific data in DOM elements, use `data-XXX` attributes, e.g. `data-bookid`

Comment: How are you calling the code, how does `element` get set? Where do you compare the `currentvalue` to `previousvalue`?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your feedback. I have made yet another update. You are completely right about the loop, it was unnecessary and I have removed it. I have also taken your syggestion and changed the attribute into `data-bookid`. You can see how the element is set in the HTML code. I am using `this` as a parametr in the function `onclick="compare(this);`. I'm not comparing the values yet, I want to first make sure that the values are actually different when I click on the second book, right now the values are the same (attached a screenshot in the update). Hopefully all is clear.

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment, you should use a global variable. You declared `previousvalue` as a local variable, so it doesn't hold the value from the previous call.

Comment: You never compare anything in the `compare()` function.

Comment: @Barmar I made another update. I know I never compared anything, because I wanted to make sure that the variables have correct values with `console.log`. I have declared 'previousvalue' as a global variable now as suggested and included the if statement to compare. This still does not work, because 'previousvalue' and 'currentvalue' are the same as in the screeenshot. Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: You need to log and compare the variables before you reassign `previousvalue`.

Comment: After the assignment, they'll always be equal.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot, it finally works! I had to include additional condition in the if statement because it only worked when clicked for the first time. You can add your suggestions as an answer and I will accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Barmar for your suggestions, I have finally implemented a working solution.

```
var previousValue;
function compare(element) {
    var currentValue = element.dataset.bookid;
    var chapterList = document.getElementById("chapter-container")

    if (previousValue == currentValue && chapterList.style.display == 'block'){
        chapterList.style.display = 'none';
    } else{
        aload(element);
    }
    previousValue = currentValue;
}
```